# Is it possible to pass a structure of data by reference to to a dynamically compiled script?

Tags: c#, dynamic

This is just an example... My "real life" example is a much more complex. Take this rough example:

```
public struct _User
{
   public string FirstName;
   public string MiddleName;
   public string LastName;
}
```

I can set the names then pass this by reference to a function.

However, I want to pass a structure of data by reference into dynamically compiled code.

```
    public void RunScript(string ScriptName, ref _User stUser)
    {
        private Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider _compiler;
        public CompilerResults _compileResults;
        private static object _compiledAssembly;

        MI.Invoke(_compiledAssembly, new object[]{
            ref stUser }); // can't do a reference here...

        MI = _compiledAssembly.GetType().GetMethod(ScriptName);

    }
```

Yes, I do have a "copy" of that structure in the dynamic code...

Is it possible to pass this structure by reference into the dynamic code?

Answer (score 3):

To start with, I think you want the two statements in the opposite order - there's no much point in setting `MI` *after* you've invoked it...

But then, you should just be able to set the value in an `object[]` which you retain a reference to - after the call, the value in the array will have changed. So you want:

```
object[] args = { stUser; }
MI.Invoke(_compiledAssembly, args);
stUser = (_User) args[0]; // Or whatever you want to do with it
```

(Do you *really* need it to be a struct at all? And with public fields, no less?)

I'm a bit perturbed by this part, by the way:

> Yes, I do have a "copy" of that structure in the dynamic code...

If you mean there's another type defined in your dynamically-generated assembly, that's a problem. The two types will *not* be the same, even if they've got the same namespace-qualified name. You should make your dynamically-generated assembly refer to the assembly containing the type. You really don't want two types with the same name in different assemblies - it will make debugging a real pain...

EDIT: Short but complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public struct MutableStruct
{
    public int x;
}

class Test
{
    public static void ChangeByRef(ref MutableStruct foo)
    {
        foo = new MutableStruct { x = 10 };
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var args = new object[] { new MutableStruct() };
        var method = typeof(Test).GetMethod("ChangeByRef");
        method.Invoke(null, args);
        var changed = (MutableStruct) args[0];
        Console.WriteLine(changed.x); // Prints 10
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that passing by value and not reference?  I need to modify the data in the struct with the dynamic function.  (the above code is example only; not functional as it was done by memory)  The real structure holds a little over 50 variables.  

For the other reflection calls I do, I have another program I wrote to create, compile and test the dynamic functions.  This dynamic function has about 13 variables I pass into it with a single string being returned based on the logic in the dynamic function.  This newer function I'm working on needs to edit the data in the struct as it has over 50 vars

Comment: I'm curious on how the struct is defined in the dynamic function if I don't create it manually within it?  I'd love to use the includes class I have that contains the struct in case it does change in the future....

Comment: @NeonBlue: It ends up effectively passing by reference, because the array is updated with whatever the parameter value is at the end of the method. I'd strongly discourage a struct with 50 variables in though.

Comment: @NeonBlue: Without knowing more context, it's hard to say anything about how or where to declare the struct. You must have already declared it otherwise you couldn't use it (`_User`) in the code you've presented.

Comment: I'm curious on the reason why you wouldn't have a struct with 50 vars in it?  It's not class material in that it's just raw data being converted from one of many data sources to a SQL DB.  The strongly type struct is helpful when programming with it.

No, the _User does not exist in my code...  The only piece I copied from my code was the MI.Invoke.  It's all prototype right now trying to figure out the reference.  Also, as I mentioned in the 2nd comment, now can I use an existing struct definition in the dynamic function? Thanks for your insight!

Comment: @NeonBlue: I think you may have misunderstood the purpose of the differences between structs and classes. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx

Comment: Yes, I have misunderstood it. Thanks for the link.  However in the name of time I'm going to leave the struct in place and come back to this code when things calm down a bit in a couple of months.  There's just way too much code to change with the time I have available...  But I've gotten some really good ideas on what I can do when I go to re-write it.


Turns out, I can't pass the same, but "different" struct because they are defined in two different classes.  You referred above how to access the struct outside of the class.  How is this done?

Comment: BTW, your suggestion doesn't work.  The args appears to be pass only, not referenced.  The variables show in the function but don't change in the args[] parameter.

Comment: @NeonBlue: It definitely works with normal reflection. I'll edit the answer with an example. I'm not sure what you mean by "access the struct outside of the class".